# pushing a pandas df together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-11', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['XLE','XLE',5,'XLE','XLE','XLE'],
                   'B':[5,5,'XLI','XLI','XLI','XLI'],
                   'C':['XLV','XLV','XLV','XLV',5,'XLV'],
                  'D':['XLY','XLY','XLY',5,'XLV',5]}, index=idx)

print (df)

              A    B    C    D
2000-01-11  XLE    5  XLV  XLY
2000-01-12  XLE    5  XLV  XLY
2000-01-13    5  XLI  XLV  XLY
2000-01-14  XLE  XLI  XLV    5
2000-01-15  XLE  XLI    5  XLV
2000-01-16  XLE  XLI  XLV    5
```

I have data in a pandas df, how can I create a new 4 column dataframe without any of the 5's?  Basically push the dataframe in for lack of better words.

Comment: also, it helps you give sample desired output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x != 5].values, index=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']), axis=1)
print (df)
           col1 col2 col3
2000-01-11  XLE  XLV  XLY
2000-01-12  XLE  XLV  XLY
2000-01-13  XLI  XLV  XLY
2000-01-14  XLE  XLI  XLV
2000-01-15  XLE  XLI  XLV
2000-01-16  XLE  XLI  XLV
```

Another solution with `numpy.sort` and selecting by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[df != 5].astype(str), axis=1),
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns = list('abcd')).iloc[:, :3]
print (df)
              a    b    c
2000-01-11  XLE  XLV  XLY
2000-01-12  XLE  XLV  XLY
2000-01-13  XLI  XLV  XLY
2000-01-14  XLE  XLI  XLV
2000-01-15  XLE  XLI  XLV
2000-01-16  XLE  XLI  XLV
```

Comment: So say one row instead of having 3 strings has 2 strings and an extra 5, is there a way to pass by the error when using apply??

Comment: Unfortunately now I am offline. Only on phone. The best is create new question with sample data, desired output and your code what you try.